# Show terms in view filtered from another view

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have two views, first one is block, second one is page. I have vocabulary, let's call it "food".
In the food vocabulary we have that hierarchy:

- Fruit

  - Apple
  - Banana
- Meat

  - Chicken
  - Pork

Both views goal is to show taxonomy terms, but first one shows ONLY parent terms, then we click on parent Fruit, we get second view, which shows ONLY terms from Fruit, so Apple and Banana. If we clicked on Meat term, we get terms Chicken and Pork. My question is how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two Views Display for that, you can do that one with one Page Display.

1. Create Views of type Taxonomy term and add Page Display
2. Add Filter for Food Vocabulary
3. Add the Parent Relationship. It is called `Taxonomy term` but look at the Description `The parent term of the term. This can produce ...`.

   If you Require it the results will only show terms that have Parent items, so you'll probably want that.
4. Add Contextual filter `Name` from the Taxonomy term Category and configure it:
   **Relationship**: `Parent`
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Display a summary**
   `Format` **List**
   `Base path` (you *must* enter the Page path if this isn't the first Page Display in your Views)
   **Display record count with link**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
   **Specify validation criteria**
   **Taxonomy term name**
   [Food]
   **Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values**
   `More`
   **Transform spaces to dashes in URL**

You will see a list of your parent items in the results (as a Summary), then when you click on one you will see Views results terms that are its children.

Comment: That is very helpful. I created one view with parents and childs as you mentioned and it's working. One last thing i need to do, i have problem with using **Format: List**, because i have custom format for it. Option **list** and **unformatted** discarding my custom format in template for this view.

Comment: I'm glad it's working! Can you share some more information about your custom Views format? This should go into a separate question. Try to answer: Can you see your custom formatter in Views when you want to change the Format? What template did you change?

Comment: I have html and php code in views-views-fields--_templatename_-display.tpl.php. So this view reads this file and shows to me food nodes. If I choose **Format: List**, it tells to view use list style instead of my template. Option **unformatted** gives me same result.